# Ошибка вывода данных из $_GET['lang'] если язык соответствует ru или en

Tags: php

Есть код с тремя условиями:

```php
$lang = $_GET['lang'] ;

if($lang == 'ru') 
{
    require  "lang/ru.php"; 
}

if($lang == 'en' )
{ 
    require  "lang/eng.php"; 
}

if ($lang != 'en' && $lang != 'ru') 
{
    require "lang/eng.php"; 
}
```

Если `$_GET['lang']` с пустым значением - все работает. 
Если же не пустое значение, а ru, или en на сайте выводятся только три скобки `<` в тех местах где я вызываю какую либо функцию ил eng.php или ru.php

Если я подключаю просто `require  "lang/eng.php";` или `require  "lang/ru.php";` - тоже все работает....

Как так?=)

Comment: И да. Включил вывод ошибок - ни одной ошибки нет....

Comment: Заголовок вопроса должен быть содержательным

Comment: Хм... У меня всё работает как надо :) Но всё равно - делал бы так: http://ideone.com/agA9pq (не очень правильно, есть там плюха, просто как подход)

Answer (score -4):

На сколько я знаю по require файлы подключаются без учёта условий. Поменяй на include.

Comment: Пробовал уже все варианты. =)

Comment: К тому же все равно. Третий вариант подключает он по условию. Тоесть выходит, что условие работает, только при условии, что $lang пустой.

Comment: Может тогда так?

`$lang = $_GET['lang'] ;
if($lang == 'ru') { include  "lang/ru.php"; }
else{ include  "lang/eng.php"; }`

Comment: "На сколько я знаю по require файлы подключаются без учёта условий." - это неверно, подчиняются if/else, как и все другое.

Comment: содержимое подключаемых файлов залейте